# JOIN command does not return results

Tags: linux

I am trying to join 2 large files(1 file is 699M and other is 20GB). Both the files have only 2 columns. The command I am using is: `join -1 2 -2 1 -t , -o 1.2,0,2.2 file1 file2`. When I try the command using a smaller `file1`, the command works fine. I tried printing `$?` to see if the exit code is non zero, but it is not.

How can I debug to find out the reason?

```
Some info:
O.S: RHEL5
Arch: x86_64
```

Comment: is `file1` and `file2` sorted?

Comment: @h3rrmiller: Yes, it is sorted !

Comment: `strace -fv join ...`

Answer (score 1):

Both files must be sorted on the join fields, and they must be sorted using the same order that is also used by `join`. A common problem is that the files are sorted using, say, `LC_COLLATE=C`, but the current value of `LC_COLLATE` (that is now used by `join`) is something else, such as `de_DE`. (`LC_COLLATE=C` and `LC_COLLATE=de_DE` differ when upper and lower case letters are compared, and they also treat whitespace differently.)